# Regex with one specific number and a word

Tags: regex

I would like to match a specific pattern with regex but I am running into catastrophic backtracking. I wonder if there's a way it would be possible to match what I would like and not get an error.
I start with a simple assumption; I want my string to contain only one specific number e.g. 7 and only that specific number:

`^\D*7\D*$`

Only if I find this pattern do I want to look for another word in the same text such as "Coffee"; I put my condition into a group `(^\D*7\D*$)` and reference the group in my conditional and the then part will contain "Coffee":

`(?(1)Coffee|)`

Is there another phrasing that would avoid the the catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: You can assert Coffee `^(?=.*\bCoffee\b)\D*7\D*$` https://regex101.com/r/ZE1M6X/1 Note that `\D` also matches a newline.

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you explain \b in regex?

Comment: @JonathanRodriguesCardoso The `\b` is a word boundary to prevent a partial match like `aCoffee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left to right checking is more traditional:

```js
^(?=.*Coffee)[^\d7]*7\D*$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/dvCYA9/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Coffee                   'Coffee'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\d7]*                  any character except: digits (0-9), '7' (0
                           or more times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7                        '7'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Right to left checking is only possible with engines like latest JavaScript, .NET or PyPi regex in Python:

```js
^[^\d7]*7\D*$(?<=Coffee.*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/dvCYA9/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\d7]*                  any character except: digits (0-9), '7' (0
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7                        '7'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Coffee                   'Coffee'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead to assert that the word `Coffee` is at the right.

```
^(?=.*\bCoffee\b)\D*7\D*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that on the right is

  - `.*\bCoffee\b` Match `Coffee` between word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\D*7\D*` Match number 7 between optional non digit characters.
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZE1M6X/1)

**Note** that `\D` also matches a newline. If you don't want to cross newline boundaries, you can use `[^\r\n\d]` instead.